# r shiny - Plotting multiple images using the imageOutput() and renderImage()

Tags: r, image, shiny, server-side-rendering

I am trying to plot several images saved in the www sub-directory folder of my shiny app folder. The image file names are in a data frame column; let’s say “img_path”.

I am using the `imageOutput()` function in the UI and `renderImage()` in the server interface.
Since I want to plot all the images in the `www` subfolder and that are referenced in the data frame, I am using a for loop.

Unfortunately, instead of rendering all the images, it always displays the last image. I guess this is happening because images are being overlayed on top of each other.

Let say that I have: my data

```
df_img <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), img_path = c("h1000.png", "h2000.png", "h3000.png", "h4000.png", "h000.png"))
```

which is stored in the data subfolder; the 5 images in the www subfolder are named as in the `df_img[["img_path"]]`.
My basic shiny app code is:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
```

## Define UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Test app"),
    # to render images in the www folder 
    box(imageOutput("houz"), width = 3)
)
```

## Define server logic

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    df_img <- read.csv("data/df_img.csv", header = T)
    for (i in 1:nrow(df_img)) {
        output$houz <- renderImage({
            list(
                src = file.path('www', df_img$img_path[i]),
                contentType = "image/jpeg",
                width = "100%", height = "45%"
            )
        }, deleteFile = FALSE)
        
    }
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[what_i_expect and what_i_get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qFLL.jpg)

Comment: That is because you have one `outputID` and therefore, it will show only the last image.

Comment: Thank you @YBS. But I don't want to have 5 different `ouputid` in the `ui` and 5 `renderImage()` in the `server`; but want to be able to automate the process; so that even if i add a `selectInput` to filter the data, the app should be able to automatically render the images based on the filtered data frame.

Comment: @Alassane I think a solution based on Shiny modules will suit your needs - please see the answer (with working example) I provided.

Comment: @Alassane, you only need one `outputID` for `renderUI`.  Please see my answer below.  You can automate this with `selectInput`.  Also, Shiny modules is a good answer, but if you are not familiar with modules programming you can use my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `renderUI` to display the list of images you wish to display.  Try this

```
df_img <- data.frame(id = c(1:5), img_path = c("h1000.png", "h2000.png", "h3000.png", "h4000.png", "h000.png"))

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Test app"),
  # to render images in the www folder 
  box(uiOutput("houz"), width = 3)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  #df_img <- read.csv("data/df_img.csv", header = T)
  
  n <- nrow(df_img)
  
  observe({
    for (i in 1:n)
    {
      print(i)
      local({
        my_i <- i
        imagename = paste0("img", my_i)
        print(imagename)
        output[[imagename]] <-
          renderImage({
            list(src = file.path('www', df_img$img_path[my_i]), 
                 width = "100%", height = "55%",
                 alt = "Image failed to render")
          }, deleteFile = FALSE)
      })
    }
  })
  
  
  output$houz <- renderUI({
    
    image_output_list <- 
      lapply(1:n,
             function(i)
             {
               imagename = paste0("img", i)
               imageOutput(imagename)
             })
    
    do.call(tagList, image_output_list)
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: you are a genius @YBS! thanks so much. But how do you reduce space between the images?

Comment: @ YBS,  i've got the solution for the space: wrapped the imageOutput in a div() with a margin-bottom style. `div(style = "margin-bottom:-12em", imageOutput(imagename))` . Thanks

Comment: Sorry, could not get to it today.  Great that you got the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Shiny modules. A working example is below, which assumes you have images with a "jpeg" extension in a "www" subdirectory of the working directory. I use `purrr` for functional programming - you could use `lapply()` or a `for` loop if you prefer.

[Chapter 19 of Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html) is a good introduction to Shiny modules.

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui_module <- function(id) {
  imageOutput(NS(id, "img"))
}

server_module <- function(id,
                          img_path) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
  output$img <- renderImage({
    list(src = img_path,
         contentType = "image/jpeg",
         width = "100%",
         height = "45%")
  },
  deleteFile = FALSE)
    })
}

images <- list.files(path = "www",
                     pattern = "jpeg",
                     full.names = TRUE)

ids <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(
  basename(images)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  map(ids, ui_module)
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  map2(.x = ids,
       .y = images,
       .f = server_module)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Woww, @MattCowgill, this is another great solution. Very efficient! (y)